# Gaming.SE turning into a helpdesk

Tags: discussion, site-policies, allowed-questions

Questions like [these](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/214983/93118) make me feel like gaming.SE is turning into a help-desk. These questions should, in my humble opinion, be considered off-topic since the help-desk of the game/platform in question should be asked instead of posting it here. It's what they're for after all.

Should such questions be considered off-topic?
If so, as what should they be marked?

Answer (score 10):

In many cases, we can answer these questions either by searching or from experience with the various platforms, software, etc.

There is no reason to mark these as off topic. If we can't answer them because they are unclear, or they require knowledge only the developers would know, etc, we have perfectly good close reasons for those things already.

If people choose to come here instead of going to a site's support, it might mean they know they will get a good answer here, or they have already tried support and gotten frustrated, or they might feel like it is a good question to ask in a public space so others with the problem can also get help.

There isn't a real need to mark these as off-topic, as they are perfectly good questions for our site, and we have been able to answer many of them, helping a lot of people.

If you see issues with specific questions, flag or vote to close as needed, but not just because they happen to be helpdesk style questions.

Comment: Agreed. The main problem we run into with these help desk type questions is that they don't give enough detail to actually help them, so it's unclear what they're asking. I think so long as people are willing to close as such while waiting for more details to be added, we're fine. It's when they are left open and people try to solve it all in the comments that they start to get messy.

Comment: @Sterno more so when they don't bother coming back after posting the question, because then despite our best efforts is trying to ask for more information they never reply and the quest effectively becomes dead. though in my experience i've mainly seen with with minecraft questions

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning that it's not like they're tangentially related and we accept them 'just because' either: It's one of our [primary on-topic points](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): *Game Specific Hardware & Utilities*. In other words, Utilities like Steam, or Origin, or Humble etc etc